# how to start puma with unix socket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, puma

I have followed [this link](http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-setup-rails-app-with-puma-and-nginx/)  to configure nginx with puma
but when I start the server with
`bundle exec puma -e development -b unix:///var/run/my_app.sock`
it throws `Permission denied - "/var/run/my_app.sock" (Errno::EACCES) error`.

but when I start the server with `bundle exec puma -e development`
it is started with  `tcp://0.0.0.0:9292`

`my_app.sock file does not exist in /var/run/`

how do I start the server with unix socket and access the application through the domain name given in the `my_app.conf` file.

Can you please anyone help me?.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To start puma with socket binding just use `/tmp` directory:

```
bundle exec puma -e development -b unix:///tmp/my_app.sock
```

To access application through domain name you should use something like `nginx` and do configuration for it.

To install `nginx` in Ubuntu just run next command:

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

Run `sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/my_app.conf` and place configuration below into this file (Ctrl + X, Y - to save changes):

```
upstream my_app {
  server              unix:///tmp/my_app.sock;
}

server {
  listen              *:80;
  server_name         my_app.com;

  access_log          /var/log/nginx/my_app-access.log;

  location /favicon.ico {
    root              /var/www/my_app/public/assets/favicon.ico;
    gzip_static       on;
    expires           max;
    add_header        Cache-Control public;
  }

  location / {
    root              /var/www/my_app/public;
    try_files         $uri @app;
    gzip_static       on;
    expires           max;
    add_header        Cache-Control public;
  }

  location @app {
    proxy_pass        http://my_app;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto http;
    proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect    off;
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_502;
  }   
}
```

You should change `/var/www/my_app` and `my_app.com` to appropriate values.

Add symlink into enabled sites `sudo ln -fns /etc/nginx/sites-available/my_app.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`

Restart nginx: `sudo service nginx restart`.

Link your domain name to server IP (via `hosts`-file or DNS-provider).

Comment: Lol, my edit was rejected. There is wrong protocol (in `request` object will be port '443', protocol 'https://' and `.ssl?` true) needs to be changed `proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto https;` to `proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;`.

Comment: @2nd Thank you for your comment. Just fixed it.

Comment: Also, in some distros (like Centos8), `systemd units` have a service setup option that instructs the system to create `private temporary files`, which means, only accessible by the same process. It may also be an issue. To prevent that, set `PrivateTmp=No` in the `[Service]` block of the service setup file.