# nginx not connecting to puma upstream

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, nginx-config, puma, nginx-upstreams

I've setup a puma server for a rails app and an nginx upstream directive but it's not routing correctly.

I'm on Ubunutu 22.10

```
root@kapelner-gradesly:~/deploy/gradeportal/current# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.10
Release:        22.10
Codename:       kinetic
```

and ruby v3.2.0

```
root@kapelner-gradesly:~/deploy/gradeportal/current# ruby -v
ruby 3.2.0 (2022-12-25 revision a528908271) [x86_64-linux]
```

I'm using `git push` and `capistrano` via `cap production deploy` for deployment. The relevant gems are below in my `Gemfile.lock` file:

```
...
    capistrano (3.17.3)
      airbrussh (>= 1.0.0)
      i18n
      rake (>= 10.0.0)
      sshkit (>= 1.9.0)
    capistrano-bundler (2.1.0)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
    capistrano-rails (1.6.3)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      capistrano-bundler (>= 1.1, < 3)
    capistrano-rvm (0.1.2)
      capistrano (~> 3.0)
      sshkit (~> 1.2)
...
    puma (6.3.0)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
    racc (1.7.1)
    rack (2.2.7)
    rack-cors (2.0.1)
      rack (>= 2.0.0)
    rack-test (2.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.3)
    rack-timeout (0.6.3)
    rails (7.0.6)
      actioncable (= 7.0.6)
      actionmailbox (= 7.0.6)
      actionmailer (= 7.0.6)
      actionpack (= 7.0.6)
      actiontext (= 7.0.6)
      actionview (= 7.0.6)
      activejob (= 7.0.6)
      activemodel (= 7.0.6)
      activerecord (= 7.0.6)
      activestorage (= 7.0.6)
      activesupport (= 7.0.6)
      bundler (>= 1.15.0)
      railties (= 7.0.6)
...

BUNDLED WITH
   2.3.21
```

My puma config file is below

```
# Default to production
rails_env = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || "production"
environment rails_env

if rails_env == "production"

    # Change to match your CPU core count
    workers 2

    # Min and Max threads per worker
    threads 1,2

    app_dir = File.expand_path("../..", __FILE__)
    shared_dir = "/root/deploy/gradeportal/shared"

    # Set up socket location
    bind 'tcp://0.0.0.0:9292'
    #bind "unix://#{shared_dir}/sockets/puma.sock"

    # Logging
    stdout_redirect "#{shared_dir}/log/puma.stdout.log", "#{shared_dir}/log/puma.stderr.log", true

    # Set master PID and state locations
    pidfile "#{shared_dir}/pids/puma.pid"
    state_path "#{shared_dir}/pids/puma.state"
    activate_control_app

    on_worker_boot do
      require "active_record"
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect! rescue ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(YAML.load_file("#{app_dir}/config/database.yml")[rails_env])
    end
end
```

and I have puma set up as a `systemctl` service:

```
root@kapelner-gradesly:~# cat /etc/systemd/system/puma.service
[Unit]
Description=Puma HTTP Server
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=notify
WatchdogSec=10
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/root/deploy/gradeportal/current
Environment=RAILS_ENV=production

ExecStart=/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/wrappers/puma -C /root/deploy/gradeportal/current/config/puma.rb
Restart=always
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The puma service is running fine:

```
root@kapelner-gradesly:~# sudo systemctl status puma
● puma.service - Puma HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/puma.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-07-18 11:54:29 EDT; 12min ago
   Main PID: 443710 (ruby)
     Status: "Puma 6.3.0: cluster: 2/2, worker_status: [{ 1/2 threads, 2 available, 0 backlog },{ 1/2 threads, 2 available, >
      Tasks: 26 (limit: 2308)
     Memory: 303.3M
        CPU: 6.930s
     CGroup: /system.slice/puma.service
             ├─443710 "puma 6.3.0 (tcp://0.0.0.0:9292) [20230714225250]"
             ├─443717 "puma: cluster worker 0: 443710 [20230714225250]"
             └─443718 "puma: cluster worker 1: 443710 [20230714225250]"

Jul 18 11:54:24 kapelner-gradesly puma[443710]: [443710] * Puma version: 6.3.0 (ruby 3.2.0-p0) ("Mugi No Toki Itaru")
Jul 18 11:54:24 kapelner-gradesly puma[443710]: [443710] *  Min threads: 1
Jul 18 11:54:24 kapelner-gradesly puma[443710]: [443710] *  Max threads: 2
Jul 18 11:54:24 kapelner-gradesly puma[443710]: [443710] *  Environment: production
Jul 18 11:54:24 kapelner-gradesly puma[443710]: [443710] *   Master PID: 443710
Jul 18 11:54:24 kapelner-gradesly puma[443710]: [443710] *      Workers: 2
Jul 18 11:54:24 kapelner-gradesly puma[443710]: [443710] *     Restarts: (✔) hot (✔) phased
Jul 18 11:54:24 kapelner-gradesly puma[443710]: [443710] * Listening on http://0.0.0.0:9292
Jul 18 11:54:24 kapelner-gradesly puma[443710]: [443710] Use Ctrl-C to stop
Jul 18 11:54:29 kapelner-gradesly systemd[1]: Started Puma HTTP Server.
```

And the port is listening and opened with `sudo ufw allow 9292/tcp` (I will close it later, I just opened it to debug.

```
root@kapelner-gradesly:~# sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
systemd        1            root   60u  IPv6   19157      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
systemd-r    563 systemd-resolve   14u  IPv4   18840      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.53:53 (LISTEN)
systemd-r    563 systemd-resolve   16u  IPv4   18842      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.54:53 (LISTEN)
mysqld       725           mysql   21u  IPv4   19934      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:33060 (LISTEN)
mysqld       725           mysql   23u  IPv4   20046      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:3306 (LISTEN)
sshd         879            root    3u  IPv6   19157      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
nginx     405901            root    8u  IPv4 2177079      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx     405901            root    9u  IPv4 2177080      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx     405902          nobody    8u  IPv4 2177079      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx     405902          nobody    9u  IPv4 2177080      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx     405903          nobody    8u  IPv4 2177079      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx     405903          nobody    9u  IPv4 2177080      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx     405904          nobody    8u  IPv4 2177079      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx     405904          nobody    9u  IPv4 2177080      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx     405905          nobody    8u  IPv4 2177079      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx     405905          nobody    9u  IPv4 2177080      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
ruby      443710            root    5u  IPv4 2999047      0t0  TCP *:9292 (LISTEN)
ruby      443717            root    5u  IPv4 2999047      0t0  TCP *:9292 (LISTEN)
ruby      443718            root    5u  IPv4 2999047      0t0  TCP *:9292 (LISTEN)
```

I can go to `kapelner.com:9292` and the webpage serves without errors (save a few asset files and whatnot which is expected since they're configured to run through `nginx` as you'll see below). Puma logs appropriately and rails logs appropriately to the following three files:

```
root@kapelner-gradesly:~/deploy/gradeportal/current/log# ls -lh
total 45M
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root    0 Jul 18 11:52 development.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  43M Jul 18 11:55 production.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  377 Jul 18 11:54 puma.stderr.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.2M Jul 18 11:54 puma.stdout.log
```

Now onto the problem...

I've got nginx v1.22

```
root@kapelner-gradesly:~/deploy/gradeportal/current# nginx -version
nginx version: nginx/1.22.0 (Ubuntu)
```

running also as a `systemctl` service:

```
root@kapelner-gradesly:~# cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service
[Unit]
Description=A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
Documentation=man:nginx(8)
After=network.target nss-lookup.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/nginx.pid
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g 'daemon on; master_process on;'
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon on; master_process on;'
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon on; master_process on;' -s reload
ExecStop=-/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid
TimeoutStopSec=5
KillMode=mixed

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

which is running fine:

```
root@kapelner-gradesly:~# sudo systemctl status nginx
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2023-07-14 18:54:59 EDT; 3 days ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
    Process: 405899 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 405900 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 405901 (nginx)
      Tasks: 5 (limit: 2308)
     Memory: 7.4M
        CPU: 5.207s
     CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
             ├─405901 "nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;"
             ├─405902 "nginx: worker process"
             ├─405903 "nginx: worker process"
             ├─405904 "nginx: worker process"
             └─405905 "nginx: worker process"

Jul 14 18:54:59 kapelner-gradesly systemd[1]: nginx.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jul 14 18:54:59 kapelner-gradesly systemd[1]: Stopped A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Jul 14 18:54:59 kapelner-gradesly systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Jul 14 18:54:59 kapelner-gradesly systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

and the configuration file checks out

```
root@kapelner-gradesly:~# nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

My nginx configuration is below:

```
root@kapelner-gradesly:~# cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
worker_processes  4;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
  multi_accept on;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    gzip off;
    gzip_vary off;

    upstream app {
     # Path to Puma SOCK file, as defined previously
     #server unix:///root/deploy/gradeportal/shared/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
     server 0.0.0.0:9292;
    }


    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

As you can see, I tried the "sock" method before, also with no luck. Here's my additional configuration file:

```
root@kapelner-gradesly:~# cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/kapelner.conf
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name kapelner.com *.kapelner.com;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
       listen   443 ssl;

       location @app {
          proxy_pass https://app;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_redirect off;
        }

        root /root/deploy/gradeportal/current/public;
        server_name kapelner.com *.kapelner.com;
        #index index.htm index.html;
        try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/kapelner.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/kapelner.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

        access_log /var/log/nginx/kapelner_access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/kapelner_error.log;

        location / {
                rewrite ^/assets(.*)$ /assets$1 break;
                rewrite ^(.*)$ /kapelner$1 break;
        }
}
```

I've also tried commenting out the `location` block with no luck either.

The problem is I'm getting a "404 not found error" when visiting `kapelner.com`.

When looking at the nginx logs I find:

```
root@kapelner-gradesly:/var/log/nginx# cat /var/log/nginx/kapelner_access.log
...
72.226.69.230 - - [18/Jul/2023:12:23:22 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 564 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

and the error officially is:

```
root@kapelner-gradesly:~# cat /var/log/nginx/kapelner_error.log
...
2023/07/18 12:29:22 [error] 444642#444642: *16 "/root/deploy/gradeportal/current/public/kapelner/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 72.226.69.230, server: kapelner.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "kapelner.com"
```

which I'm interpreting to mean that it's not connecting to puma on the upstream.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

I've revamped my config file to:

```
root@kapelner-gradesly:~# cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/kapelner.conf
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name kapelner.com *.kapelner.com;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
       listen   443 ssl;

       #location @app {
       #   proxy_pass https://app;
       #   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       #   proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       #   proxy_redirect off;
       # }

        root /root/deploy/gradeportal/current/public;
        server_name kapelner.com *.kapelner.com;
        #index index.htm index.html;
        try_files $uri @app;

        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/kapelner.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/kapelner.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

        access_log /var/log/nginx/kapelner_access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/kapelner_error.log;

        location / {
                rewrite ^/assets(.*)$ /assets$1 break;
                rewrite ^(.*)$ /kapelner$1 break;
        }

}
```

and restarted nginx. Then I still get the same error message:

```
root@kapelner-gradesly:~# cat /var/log/nginx/kapelner_error.log
...
2023/07/18 13:40:32 [error] 445188#445188: *2 "/root/deploy/gradeportal/current/public/kapelner/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 72.226.69.230, server: kapelner.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "kapelner.com"
```

Maybe there is something else in the other included `conf` files. Here's

```
root@kapelner-gradesly:~# cat /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf
ssl_session_cache shared:le_nginx_SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout 1440m;
ssl_session_tickets off;

ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-<cipher continues, no need to show it>-SHA384";
```

There's nothing else in the `conf.d` folder:

```
root@kapelner-gradesly:~# cd /etc/nginx/conf.d
root@kapelner-gradesly:/etc/nginx/conf.d# ls -lh
total 4.0K
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.1K Jul 18 13:39 kapelner.conf
```

and nothing in the `sites-enabled` directory:

```
root@kapelner-gradesly:/etc/nginx# cd sites-enabled/
root@kapelner-gradesly:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# ls -lh
total 0
```

This is super strange. Anything else I can try?

Comment: Since a `GET /` is being mapped to loading `/kapelner/index.html`, it looks like that second location block is being used instead of the first one. But you said commenting out that block (and restarting nginx after doing so) produces the same behavior?

Comment: I commented out the location block and I deleted the `$uri/index.html` directive as well. Same 404 and same error in `kapelner_access.log`.

Comment: Sorry to mention this again, but you're sure you restarted nginx (or reloaded the configuration) after making those updates? Just want to rule that out. The error message should be _slightly_ different after removing the location with the rewrites.

Comment: See question edit. Yes, same thing. Really weird. I've been battling this for days. Now I'm hoping someone can give me some new ideas to try.

Comment: Looking at your edit, I see you commented out the first location (with your proxy pass to puma); what happens if you comment out the second location (with the rewrites)?

Answer (score 0):

You are naming your upstream `app` in the `http` section, but your server_name doesn't match your upstream name.

Try the following

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name app;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

And hopefully, it will work. Here is a reference configuration [how to start puma with unix socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17450672/how-to-start-puma-with-unix-socket).

Comment: Thanks. I tried what you wrote. Still same error.

Comment: Is there any way to do an isolated test on the upstream app connecting to port 9292 where puma is running?

Comment: For instance, I commented out the entire `upstream` block and still get the same error. So I think it's being "passed over" in some way.

Comment: It's possibly nginx is busted. I can try reinstalling. But I doubt that will help.

Comment: Have you tried the settings in the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17450672/how-to-start-puma-with-unix-socket ? Maybe you are missing other things, for example `location @app`